# Creating dynamic buttons in angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, button, angular-material, nested-loops

I am creating an angular application. I have created 5 mat flat buttons using angular material.
code

```
<button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 1 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(1)">B-L1</button>
<button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 2 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(2)">B-L2</button>
<button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 3 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(3)">B-L3</button>
<button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 4 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(4)">B-L4</button>
<button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 5 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(5)">B-FC</button>
```

When clicked on each button, a function is called from .ts file. code

```
change(n) {
    this.selected = n;
    if (n == 3){
      this.floor = 'BL3'
    }
    else if (n==4){
      this.floor  = 'BL4'
    }
    else if (n==2){
      this.floor  = 'BL2'
    }
    else if(n==1){
      this.floor  = 'BL1'
    }
    else if(n==5){
      this.floor  = 'BFC'
    }

    console.log('changing floor to' + this.floor)
    this.getData(this.floor)
}
```

`this.getData(this.floor)` makes an api call and gets data for that floor. Here B is a block, and L1,L2,L3.. are floors in that block.

I want to add a new block D which has L1,L2,L3,L4 floors. I can add more buttons for DL1,DL2,DL3 by adding more buttons manually. But how can i do it dynamically like if I select a master button B or D and floors within that block are displayed with the current functionality not being lost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bejzb5?file=app/app.component.html)

```
  <button md-raised-button *ngFor="let item of myButtons; let i = index" 
          (click)="changeActive(i)" #disable>{{item.name}} Basic</button>
```

.ts

```
    myButtons = [
    { name: 'Button 1' },
    { name: 'Button 2' },
    { name: 'Button 3' }
  ];

  lastClickedIndex;
  changeActive(i) {
    console.log("clicked ",i)
    this.lastClickedIndex = i;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppdm6p)

Add below code inside the component file

```
selected:any;
floorSelected:any;
block:any;
changeBlock(block){
   if(block){
     this.block = block;
   }
 }
selectedFloor(floor,block){
  if(floor){
    this.selected = floor;
    this.floorSelected = block+'L'+floor;
  }
  console.log( this.floorSelected );
}
```

And make changes in the HTML page as follows,

```
<div>
   <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == i ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="changeBlock('B')">B</button>
   <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == i ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="changeBlock('D')">D</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="block">
   <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]" >
      <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == i ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="selectedFloor(i,block)">{{block}}-L{{i}}</button>
   </div>
</div>
```